# Difference between SVM and GD/SGD?

Tags: classification, svm, gradient-descent, text-classification

My colleague mentioned that a data science project is using SGD classifier.

So I started reading about GD/SGD and came across a nice [article](https://medium.com/machine-learning-intuition/document-classification-part-3-detection-algorithm-support-vector-machines-gradient-descent-282316b0838e) about Text classification using SVM and GD.

In the end of the article the author mentions:

> We begin with a bunch of documents to train on. We then represent each
>   documents as numerical vectors, and you can choose to split them into
>   n-grams and weigh these n-grams with TF-IDF. Now that we have a
>   numerical representation, we can give the program training data and
>   make it guess each time. Based on how wrong the program was, the
>   program adjusts to its mistakes to make better prediction the next
>   time using Gradient Descent. It keeps track of its learning using SVMs
>   and make predictions with the SVM model by “plotting” the new
>   datapoint in the graph and seeing if it is on the right or left by the
>   decision boundary.

The article does not mention about SGD, but from internet research I understand that SGD is a variation of GD where-in the parameter is tweaked immediately at each iteration, rather than at the end of the entire training set.

So to me it appears that SVM is the actual **classifier** and GD (or SGD) is the **function** that tells the classifier how correctly it has done the prediction based on which the SVM classifier improves itself.

Coming back to my original question: Is my understanding right that SGD is not the classifer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,gradient descent (GD) and Stochastic Gradient Descent(SGD) are Optimization functions.Objective of a Optimization function is  to give the best combinations of parameters for our algorithm which minimize the error.Support Vector Machine is the Classification algorithm and GD/SGD are the optimization functions use to find best optimal hyperplane(separator).

Gradient Descent’s cost-function(total error of the training set) iterates over ALL training samples

Stochastic Gradient Descent’s cost-function only accounts for ONE training sample, chosen at random